# clj-condo redefined-var warning for redefined factory function of record

Tags: clojure, clj-kondo

I am using a [defrecord](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord) form to define a type in Clojure:

```
(defrecord HideTableColumnMarker [columns-resize]
  ControlMarker)
```

But I am not happy with the default factory function function from the defrecord form, so I overwrite it with my own implementation to provide a 0-arity:

```
(defn ->HideTableColumnMarker
  ([] (HideTableColumnMarker. :cut))
  ([x] (HideTableColumnMarker. x)))
```

Running clj-kondo gives a [redefined-var](https://github.com/clj-kondo/clj-kondo/blob/64bdf9fd72eda271372ff0145270ac7dbee9ff54/doc/linters.md#redefined-var) error:

```
src/stencil/types.clj:28:1: warning: redefined var #'stencil.types/->HideTableColumnMarker
```

Which makes sense but I did it on purpose. I have tried to `undef` the var from the namespace before the `defn` form but the warning message remains. How can I fix the warning without changing the configuration for clj-kondo?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `#_:clj-kondo/ignore` before the `defn`, which should ignore all warnings in the following expression.

See [the clj-kondo docs](https://github.com/clj-kondo/clj-kondo/blob/master/doc/config.md#ignore-warnings-in-an-expression)